# How can I keep my hidden fields like api key after getting bundle in CRA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, owasp, websecurity

I have a simple interface but I work with multiple APIs so I don't want to use a backend for it. How can I hide my `API keys` in CRA without using backend.

It is suggested to use environment variables for this and I have also used it as shown in the documentation but this is not exactly what I want. Even though I use environment variables , a simple CTRL + F search in the "chunk.js" files reveals things that should remain hidden, like my API keys. Is there a way to completely prevent this?

Comment: Long story short, if it's in the front end, someone could find it. There's no way to hide it. If you have private keys you don't want other people to know, you need your own backend. Even if it's just a super light one that is essentially a proxy between your front end and the services you need the keys for.

Comment: I think this is the most effective solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really, and otherwise they could sniff them out with wireshark easily enough or other network monitoring tools.

The way to combat this is making your own api that connects with the other api's, that returns the required content.
Then they need to obtain a license key for your api, that you can revoke from your server as valid if you wish to refuse access to a publicly traded license key to your api.

Comment: For example, I'm using the NASA api to pull photos of the day data. Isn't it unnecessary to use a backend for this? or I'm using firebase, when I examined it, firebase's private keys were also visible

Comment: @Dennis if you don't want your api keys public, for example when they aren't limited to your domain as origin, then you'll have to make your own backend as a proxy.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do that. I was able to do it with a small express backend service but it's the same for apps like firebase. When I use Firebase on the frontend, my private keys are exposed again.

Comment: @Dennis You'll have to write a wrapper for that too, so it connects with your api, that connects to firebase. It only needs to proxy the data, but adding your private keys that are stored on your server. So the "JS" will see your api as the firebase. Your api will just replace your api's keys with the firebase api's keys and patch it along to firebase, then on the way back remove sensitive data before returning it to the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use any API key in JS bundle like this it will be bundled, either you bundle it or you don't.

So you can:

1. Bundle API key with JS(not secure)
2. Get API key via API endpoint
3. Can obfuscate key in client bundle https://github.com/anseki/gnirts , but it's still not secure and somebody can figure it out eventually.